# Access: Compare current field value in subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a subquery in MS Access where the having clause compares a value on the current record. I created the queries separate, but am having a hard time trying to combine them.

I have the following query, which is a Purchase Order list (POsFullDetail), and should show the first occurrence of the date of a PO given the Stock number (Stockum):

```
SELECT POsFullDetail.PO, POsFullDetail.OrderDate, POsFullDetail.StockNum, 


(SELECT First(POsFullDetail.OrderDate) AS FirstOfOrderDate
FROM POsFullDetail
GROUP BY POsFullDetail.StockNum
HAVING POsFullDetail.StockNum = POsFullDetail.StockNum.Value
ORDER BY First(POsFullDetail.OrderDate)

) AS First_Date


FROM POsFullDetail;
```

The statement that I am trying to work with is POsFullDetail.StockNum.Value
The way  it is set up, it's asking for a value. When I created the subquery separate I entered the stock number directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery gives you the first order date per stocknum.

When using it as a subquery, you are no longer interested in the first order date *per* stocknum, but in the first order date for *the* stocknum.

```
SELECT POsFullDetail.PO, POsFullDetail.OrderDate, POsFullDetail.StockNum, 
  (
    SELECT First(SameStockNum.OrderDate) AS FirstOfOrderDate
    FROM POsFullDetail AS SameStockNum 
    WHERE SameStockNum.StockNum = POsFullDetail.StockNum
  ) AS First_Date
FROM POsFullDetail;
```

As you see, you must use a table alias, so you can link the table to itself. Though working with the same table you call it one time POsFullDetail and one time SameStockNum which enables you to link by `SameStockNum.StockNum = POsFullDetail.StockNum`.